# WriteFile on a file over a network share

Tags: visual-c++, networking, share, writefile

I have a program which reads and write large data. The read and write works well when the write is to a file on the local drive. When the target is a network share, and when I run two instances of the same program, the first started program hangs on WriteFile. When I debugged, the WriteFile on the network share is blocking.

I implemented a Overlapped IO on WriteFile with WaitForSingleObject(timeout 60 Sec). Now the WriteFile does not block anymore, but not even once the whole data is getting written over the network once. Do I have to consider retries when I use WriteFile over a network share?? How to use WriteFile properly on a file over the network?

Update:

I refered the following link to implement the overlapped IO with WriteFile.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/a5e9514b-53e0-410c-a975-41a5ca91e4be

The link says that I have use CreateFile with GENERIC_WRITE alone without GENERIC_READ. But what if I want also to read from the file also - does it mean that I cannot implement asyn io for WriteFile at all. Actually I have to read a header from the same file before writing on to the file with Overlapped IO. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

Your approach on using overlapped IO is correct. But how much data you are writing in one go?
WriteFile would either succeed of fail, there is not need to implement retries. You may however write data in parts, rather than writing as a whole.

You mentioned you are using file-share, that means you are writing into a file. Why not use CopyFile instead; or copy all data into file and send over network?

Comment: The readfile reads data to a buffer asynchronously and buffer is passed to the writefile. This is a raw file IO optimized for speed. The problem is only when I try to write the data to a network share. Does retrying makes sense in this case?

Comment: I guess I got the answer to this one. One MSDN forum link says that CreateFile with GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE flags will behave synchronously with WriteFile function. But if I use only GENERIC_WRITE in CreateFile, WriteFile will return network error when network connection goes down. Will test and confirm the same.